The universal selector * overrides more specific selectors in CSS for JavaFX FXML
I'm making a dictionary application with JavaFX and Kotlin.
Here is my code:
<VBox spacing="20" alignment="TOP_CENTER">
    <HBox spacing="20" alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
        <VBox id="top">
            <Label text="This text is fixed to size=13" style="-fx-font-size: 13 !important;"/>
            <Label fx:id="wordName" id="a"/>
            <Label fx:id="wordPronunciation" id="b"/>
        </VBox>
    </HBox>
</VBox>

* {
    -fx-font-size: 13
}

.label {
    -fx-font-size: 40;
}

I learned that both .class, #id override *, but * is overriding .label:

If I remove * {...} then .label {...} works well (Here I think * is overriding .label):

What I tried which didn't worked:

Using #id instead
Using !important

Adding style="-fx-font-size: 40 !important;" directly in FXML worked but I want to make it in CSS.

This is a bit of a guess, but I suspect the * selector is directly applying to the text element that is internally used as part of the label. Try .label, .label * as the selector for your specific rule (directly selecting the internals of the label). Note though that by default, font size is inherited. So a better way to define a default font size for the application would be to use .root { -fx-font-size: 13;}, after which the selector for the label should work as you have it.

@AHaworth This is a JavaFX question (using CSS to style the JavaFX UI). There is no HTML and it is not a browser based app.

@James_D Thank you so much! Both using .root instead of * and using .label, .label * worked for me!
